# Does zero correlation always imply that the two variables are not related, even in a smaller sample?

Tags: correlation

If we find that two variables are not correlated ( correlation coefficient is very weak or exactly 0) in a large population, then is it possible that over a smaller, more concentrated population, there may still be significant correlation between the two?

I am referring to [this Skeptic SE answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/30153/214) here which says there is no correlation between porn use and erectile dysfunction (ED). Could it be that the usage of porn leads to ED for some, but helps to combat ED in others, and these two effects cancel out each other and thus result in weak or no correlation on a general scale?

If the answer to the above question is yes, then one of the implications is that the urologists should also prohibit porn use for erectile dysfunction patients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about the possibility here of a missing explanatory variable (in your scenario, one that [interacts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_%28statistics%29) with porn usage in its effect on erectile dysfunction).

It's not necessary to have an interaction for a problem like this to arise; you can get it as long as the ignored variable is not evenly distributed across the variables you do have (see [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson's_paradox), especially the diagram which shows that correlation can even have entirely the wrong sign if you ignore such a variable, even if the direction of the relationship is the same within both groups!).

Clearly if you [ignore an important variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omitted-variable_bias), then that can lead to an important relationship looking like no relationship, or vice-versa (or worse make the correlation look like the opposite sign to what the actual conditional relationship is). Or there may be [another variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lurking_variable) that's causing both the ones you observe to change together, even though they're not connected.

There's also the issue that it's possible to have [*dependence* that is not linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence)*  -- two things may be strongly related but uncorrelated (e.g. what if erectile dysfunction is highest if you watch no porn and if you watch a lot of porn, and lowest in between? That could show up as zero correlation, but would not imply that you are safe with all levels of porn activity).

*(see bottom row of first diagram there Edit: the image also appears in pzsolt's answer)

There are a variety of other ways in which you might have what looks like zero correlation not implying "no relationship" --- or conversely, there are a number of situations where there appears to be a relationship but there's really no causal connection at all.

There's much more that could be said -- for example, I haven't even touched on spurious regression yet (though it's related to some of the things I have mentioned).

Comment: If that's the case, how can we make sure that there is no relationship whatsoever between two variables?

Comment: @Graviton How indeed? If it's not under experimental control (where you can at least randomize to control - at least probabilistically - for effects you don't even know about), it's a difficult and complex area that has occupied many keen minds (especially when it comes to causality) -- too difficult and complex for a brief comment, but perhaps suitable for a new question.

Comment: Well, I've asked [the question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/174489/175)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Pearson correlation, then it is definitely possible. Pearson correlation only describes the strength of linear correlation 
(y = B*x+ A), so if the variables are correlated in a higher order (for example y = x ˇ2), then the Pearson correlation's value will be 0 or close to that.[image]

(Image by Denis Bigelot, from [Wikimedia commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Correlation_examples2.svg); image has been placed in the public domain)

Comment: Please give proper attribution for the diagram; wikimedia commons gives information for how to do that, and the details you need to figure out what's required will be on the page for the diagram.

Comment: Is there any other correlationn definition that doesn't suffer the same problem as Pearson correlation does?

Comment: @Glen_b Sorry, for the lack of citing. Could you give a link to an explanation how to use wikimedia pictures?

Comment: @Graviton That's another complex question not really answerable in a couple of lines. Several questions on our site do touch on more general measures of association.

Comment: @pzsolt probably worth asking on meta! Short version: Click on the image where you see it on wikipedia, which takes you to the [image page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Correlation_examples2.svg). Note the "author"s name (DenisBoigelot). Then look for the license for this image, (which line also has a link to an outline of the [requirements](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons:Reusing_content_outside_Wikimedia) are for re-using images).  For some licenses you then need to read on to other things to get all the details.... ctd

Comment: ctd ... In this case the image has been released to the public domain (which means as far as Wikimedia commons is concerned, you can use it how you like, though they still ask that you attribute the original -- but in any case to satisfy *StackExchange* rules relating to acknowledging sources you'd still better acknowledge the author and link to the image webpage). So this one is easy. I'll edit your answer to give something like the sort of thing that should be sufficient when there's no additional license restrictions.

Comment: "Is there any other correlationn definition that doesn't suffer the same problem as Pearson correlation does?" Pearson correlation has no innate problem :D. The question you are asking touches the main cornerstones of regression analysis. I don't think there is or will be an algorithm for checking all possible correlation types. However when you are looking for correlation you need to look at the data pattern on a plot, from there you make a hypothesis on the possible correlation, which you can later check. In case of Pearson correlation you assume that the connection is linear.