# How to ensure that there is absolutely no relationship whatsoever between two variables?

Tags: correlation, independence

This question is inspired by [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174465/does-zero-correlation-always-imply-that-the-two-variables-are-not-related-even/174469?noredirect=1#comment329821_174468).

From [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/174465/175), we know that zero correlation doesn't always mean two variables are related, so my question now is, how to ensure that there is absolutely no relationship whatsoever between two variables?

Comment: Is the sample size large?

Comment: @MichaelM, assume that the sample size is already sufficiently large

Comment: I don't think there is a way to prove independence. What you can do is examine as many possible dependences as you can and reject them. (Although be aware that 95% confidence level allow for 5% false positives.)

Comment: The correctness of the answer will depend on what you mean by "variable" and "relationship." For instance, are you referring to data or to mathematical constructs? If the latter, then by "no relationship" do you mean *independent* or something else?

Comment: There are a lot of different kinds of correlation that you can calculate. You're talking about pearson correlation. This paper may help you learn about others to research: http://arxiv.org/pdf/0912.3295.pdf

Comment: @whuber, I am referring to data. We have two sets of data that we need to ascertain their relationship ( or lack of)

Comment: @SamuelReid, how does Pearson correlation ( or other kind of correlation) helps in this case ?

Comment: If you have data, there is no way to "ensure ... absolutely no relationship."  There will *always* be "relationships" among the *data*; and you cannot ensure anything about a *model* from any finite amount of data.

Comment: @Graviton As lots of comments say, you can't ensure anything. I just thought you'd be interested in other kinds of correlation, because they can estimate different types of relationships between data (while pearson does specifically linear). So at least you can get a better understanding of the relationship.